# How can I repair y - axis of hyperbola?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this hyperbola. I tried

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1} 
    
    \draw[thick, ->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,-6) -- (0,8) node[above]{$y$};
            \draw (0,4) node[right]{$4$};
       \draw [fill=black] (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
                \draw[thick] plot[domain=-2.5:2.5] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw[thick] plot[domain=-2.5:2.5] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
    \draw[thick] (0,4) circle[radius = 3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got
[image]

I want to increase value of y, e.g. [image]

How can I repair?

Comment: What do you mean by "increase y"? What would you like to change? Except for the black bar both plots look the same to me.

Comment: I want y from -2 to 8, not like first picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think now I may understand better. You want to change the plot range. AFAIK `asinh` is not implemented in pgf at this point but for moderately large negative arguments you can approximate

```
sinh(x) = (exp(x) - exp(-x))/2 ~ -exp(-x)/2 for x << -1
```

implying that

asinh(x) ~ -2 ln(|x|) .

Therefore, we might choose the domain to be `domain=-{ln(4)}:3`,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1} 

    \draw[thick, ->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,-2) -- (0,8) node[above]{$y$};
            \draw (0,4) node[right]{$4$};
       \draw [fill=black] (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \begin{scope}
     \draw[thick] plot[domain=-{ln(4)}:3] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
     \draw[thick] plot[domain=-{ln(4)}:3] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \end{scope}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
    \draw[thick] (0,4) circle[radius = 3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively we could just clip.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1} 

    \draw[thick, ->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,-2) -- (0,8) node[above]{$y$};
    \draw (0,4) node[right]{$4$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,4) circle[radius=1.5pt] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \clip (-6,-2) rectangle (6,8);
    \draw[thick] plot[domain=-2.5:2.5] ({\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw[thick] plot[domain=-2.5:2.5] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
    \draw[thick] (0,4) circle[radius = 3];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With pgfplots this becomes almost trivial: `ymin=-2`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{1} 
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xtick=\empty,ytick={4},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis equal image,
    ymin=-2,ymax=8,
    domain=-2.5:2.5]
    \draw [fill=black] (0,4) circle[radius=1.5pt] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5pt];
    \addplot[thick] ({\a*cosh(x)},{\b*sinh(x)});
    \addplot[thick] ({-\a*cosh(\x)},{\b*sinh(\x)});
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
    \draw[thick] (0,4) circle[radius = 3];
  \end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]